# how should I show the already selected object in view

Tags: angularjs

I am passing the Id values based on the Id value my view page should display the name of that Id.

eg:

```
[ {'id':1;'name':'viji'} ,{'id':2;'name':'venkat'}, {'id':3;'name':'eniya'}]
```

And also I need to get the object of the selected Id with the name in `ng-model="vendorObj"`.

```
<select ng-disabled="isView" ng-model="vendorObj" name="vendorname" ng-options="data.name for data in customerList | orderBy:'name' track by data.id"  ng-change="obj(vendorObj)">
   <option ng-readonly="isView" value=""></option>
</select>
```

Could any one tell me how to fix this?

Comment: can you put your code in plunkr

Comment: You could write a filter function, which get the id, given the name but it must exist a better solution

Answer (score 0):

I have made required changes in JSON data.
You don't require the  element in html.
Have a look at the fiddle here - [open fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/satyendon/fgb0qv7s/1/)

```
 angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyCntrl', function($scope){
$scope.dataList = [
    {'id':1,'name':'viji'} ,
  {'id':2,'name':'venkat'},
  {'id':3,'name':'eniya'}
];
$scope.func = function(a_selectedData) {
    console.log('a_selectedData', a_selectedData);
}
});
```

Comment: Hope it helps. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want selected objects's`name` in list. You can do as follows:

```
ng-options="data.name as data.name for data in customerList | orderBy:'name' track by data.id"
```